# Find distance as function of time.

Tags: physics

A car starts from rest and accelerates in $a = \frac{2\cdot m}{3\cdot s^3}t$,

After $3$ seconds, The car will be $27$ metres from beginning.

Find distance as function of time.

I know i have to integral the acceleration,But i don't know how.

I found the Equation is $x_{t} = 24 + \frac{1}{3} t^2$.

What do you think ?

Comment: This makes no sense. If the initial speed is 0 and the acceleration is 2/3 then the distance is $t^2/3$ giving a distance 3 m at 3 s, not 27.

Comment: I completely agree. This doesn't make sense. By the way, units of $a$ seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$a(t) = v'(t) = x''(t)$; we integrate acceleration to find velocity, than integrate that to find position as a function of time. We're given $a(t) = \frac{2}{3}t$ and the initial values $x(0) = 0, v(0) = 0$ (because the car starts from rest) and $x(3) = 27$. Can you figure out $x(t)$ from here?

Comment: I got your point.
But should I do integral for what ? $\int \frac{2}{3}t$ or $\int \frac{2}{3}t^2$ ?
I have some mis-understaing with the context of integration and velocity,acceleration and position.

Comment: Take it one step at a time. $v(t) = \int a(t) \, dt = \int \frac{2}{3} \, dt = \frac{2}{3}t + C_1$. Follow a similar process to find $x(t) = \int v(t) \, dt$, then use the initial values to find $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally submitted before I was finished. See my edited version.

Comment: $a(t) = \frac{2}{3}t$.
$v(t) = \int a(t) = \frac{1}{3}t^2 + v_{0}$.
$x(t) = \int v(t) = \frac{1}{9} + v_{0}t+x_{0}$.
$27 = \frac{1}{9}t^{3}+x_{0}$.
the final eqation is - $x(t) = \frac{1}{9}t^3+24$.
What do you think ?

Comment: Ah, if the acceleration is nonconstant, that explains everyone's confusion. Editing my answer.

Comment: @Noam Yes, that looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$

Since the car starts from rest, $u=0$ and $x(t)=\frac{1}{2}at^2$

If $x(3)=27$, then $a=3m/s^2$

The equation is $x(t)=\frac 32 t^2$

Comment: $a = \frac{2\cdot m}{3\cdot s^2}$

Comment: That would mean it didn't start at $x=0$. Else, it's an impossible question.